# Ubuntu Software font too bad in Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: software-center, fonts, 21.10

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to Ubuntu 21.04. Then upgraded 21.04 to 21.10 Impish Indri. During the process there were a lot of errors. Anyway at last I landed on Ubuntu 21.10. When I opened the store, there are bad fonts. See [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBgwL.png)
and [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBdjK.png) and last [Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5vGH.png). So how do I fix it?

Thanks for any answers or helps!

Comment: 20.04 -> 21.04 is not a supported upgrade path. Rather free install than upgrading so many times. However, that is the last option. Meanwhile, someone may be able to answer how to fix this particular problem.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi same problem here and I upgraded from 21.04. The font in the Ubuntu software app is bogus (pixelized) and also in Inkskape.

Comment: @chmike Try `sudo snap remove inkscape && sudo apt install inkscape`

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Thanks. Tthis solves the problem of inkscape. For Ubunty software I had to use the solution provided in the other question